# How do I view CLOB/BLOB data in DBVisulaizer?

Tags: database, blob, clob, dbvisualizer

I am trying to retrieve some CLOB/BLOB data from my database using the DBVisualizer. Could someone please tell me how I could do that? 
Any other tool/options outside DBVis would also be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

BLOB/Binary/CLOB support is available in the DbVisualizer Pro edition. If you are already using Pro, please use Help->Contact Support in DbVisualizer to report the issue.